# Getting Error: "React Native is not installed"

Tags: react-native, expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckVh1.png)

When I'm going to execute the command expo start, give me the following error, I'm starting to work with react native and I don't manage much, what can it be?

```js
app.json

   

 {
  "expo": {
    "name": "Project",
    "slug": "Project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```js
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

new error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OYEE.png)

folders
[image]

I changed the files in the folder

\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

in

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

for

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

now this error is showing up

[image]

this last error was solved by installing the expo directly on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

As it is shown in the error, `React Native` is not installed. So,

(1) `npm install`

(2) `npm start`

That's it. If you still get any problem, please update your question by containing your `app.json` file content.

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem is with your `sdk` version. Please try changing the version of the `sdk` version.

(1) replace your `package.json` with the following content. (Copy and Paste)

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Above, I've changed the `sdk` version from `38` to `37`.

(2) Delete `node_module`, and `.expo` folders if they have been created in your project root directory.

(3) `npm install`

(4) `npm start`

That's it. It should work now!

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` content to your QUESTION ?

Comment: I was able to edit the post, sorry for the delay, I still don't know how to use this site.

Comment: It's ok. No worries. I've updated my answer. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: You must change react-native in the package.json and remove the URL and put a specific version, this happens because apparently it is taking too long to download the package from github and that's why when you run the command it is not installed.

Comment: Did you mistakenly deleted the `app.json` file? Please check if it is exist.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I didn't see your answer, I edited the post and put what's in the app.json file

Comment: this last error was solved by installing the expo directly on the emulator, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the source of react-native in your package.json by changing this line:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
```

for this

```
"react-native": "^0.63.0",
```

Comment: hi, I tried, but I continue the error, I updated the post with the new error.